# Attempting to sign out after session time out

Tags: c#, asp.net

A website I am working with breaks after the session has been idle for 20 mins. It is not properly disposing of the session cookies and returning to the sign in page as it should.

```
protected void lnkSignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }

    // HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon(); Added this an attempted fix
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET so I am unfamiliar with how sessions are handled. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem exactly ? Does it logs you out after 20 mins idle ?

Comment: It times out the session, but if you click the sign out button, rather than sending you to the login page it crashes the website.

Comment: Has session timeout set in web.config ? Did you check ?

Comment: Yes, it is set to 20 mins.

Comment: So, it should be specified on the web.config as `loginUrl="~/whateverurlyouwant.aspx" `. After the session expires, user will be automatically redirected to this page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set something like this in webconfig:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms 
          name="WhateverYourAuthNameIs" 
          loginUrl="login.aspx" 
          defaultUrl="default.aspx" 
          protection="All" 
          timeout="20"  
          cookieless="AutoDetect"
        </forms>
      </authentication>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Read more about it here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.85).aspx